# What's this Encoding?!! Weird (.ini) file encoding

Tags: encoding, encode

I am trying to edit a translation of a website, the translation is in a (.INI) file.
I can't know what's the encoding of this file, AND I can't read the translating words.
Example of translation:

```
    &#1605;&#1578;&#1575;&#1581;
```

Or full line:

```
    calerdar_AvailableText                                          = "&#1605;&#1578;&#1575;&#1581;"
```

I concluded that every part the code Presents a ONE Letter. like this part: &#1605, is a letter.

Hint: You can copy and past this code to Google and it will automatically converted to words.

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File is in correct encoding(maybe utf8)...

"متاح" - is valid text, in correct encoding. You can use google transtale from Arabic, and there would be valid translation.

**Edited:**

If you need to decode html entities from strings, you can use:

`html_entity_decode('&#1605;&#1578;&#1575;&#1581;');`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put the encoding words as a code so StackOverFlow had converted it to a valid text, please check my question again.

Comment: It is standard HTML entities, added php function call sample to answer that will decode those entities.

Comment: Thanks much, I copied and renamed the file to .html then opened it by browser which allowed me to get a valid text. but I needed to add "<br>" to make new lines.